# Bootstrap Carousel Percentages

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Whenever I try to edit the height of a Bootstrap Carousel in percentage form(e.g, 100%) the carousel doesn't respond. How do I make the height of it 100%?

```
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item">
      <img class="first-slide" src="https://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/static/osx-preview/overview/hero/image_large.jpg" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Utah Unicycling Society</h1>
          <p>The only Unicycling Society in Utah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/187/cache/canyons-utah_18730_990x742.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <a href="Our-Team.html" id="join"><h1 style="color:#FFF">Join Us!</h1></a>
          <p>Today, millions of people are realizing that unicycling is great. Join the Utah Unicycling Society, and become a better unicyler today.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="third-slide" src="New pictures/Hands Low.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <a href="Donations.html" id="join"><h1 style="color:#FFF">Donate</h1></a>
          <p>We can't get money if you don't donate!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="fourth-slide" src="TheRoad.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>The Road to Success</h1>
          <p>Here at Utah Unicycling Society, we believe in the road to success, and follow it every day.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

and the css

```
    .carousel-inner{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
```

Please help, if you can!!!

Comment: Please provide some sample code of this behavior so we can help you debug it.

Comment: Have you tried resizing the outer carousel div? Also, height:100% does not mean 100% of the screen, it means that .carousel inner and it content fill the entire height of the div its inside of/just above it.

Comment: Here is my website if you want to see it

Comment: http://utahunicyclingsociety.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The carousel will respond to your img.
Define the "slide" class with the height you want like:

```
.first-slide {
     height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Do that for all the four slides.